# Django `request_started ` signal - Not Triggered

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-signals

Hi all I am using the Django `request_started` signal to log django request. I could not see the logs

```
from django.core.signals import request_started
from django.dispatch import receiver

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@receiver(request_started)
def log_request(sender, environ, **kwargs):
    method = environ['REQUEST_METHOD']
    path = environ['PATH_INFO']
    logger.info(f"{method} {path}")
```

Comment: Do you load the module somewhere so that `receiver` could add `log_request()` to handlers?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver

I followed this and it does not say to load anywhere

Comment: Did you do the thing in the green box? Where it says `Implicitly connect a signal handlers decorated with @receiver`?

Comment: did you import the signals.py  file in apps.py ready method?